# How make user stay logged-in, in Firebase react even after page refresh?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a firebase app with react. I want the login state to be persistent even after page refresh. Currently when I refresh the page my redux slice goes back to it's initial state.

My firebaseConfig file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDJECv1Q0Jal7-j8z1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "1:974xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
//auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);
export default app;
```

My redux authSlice:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { GoogleAuthProvider, signOut, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithPopup} from "firebase/auth"
import { auth } from "../../config/firebaseConfig";


const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState: {
        uid : null,
        email: null,
        displayName : null,
        photoURL : null,
    },

    reducers: {
        removeUser(state, action) {
            state.uid = null;
            state.email= null;
            state.displayName = null;
            state.photoURL = null;
        },

        addUser(state, action){
            state['uid'] = action.payload.uid;
            state['email'] = action.payload.email;
            state['displayName'] = action.payload.displayName;
            state['photoURL'] = action.payload.photoURL;
        }

    }
});


export const { removeUser,  addUser } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;


export function signInWithGoogle(){
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
            const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider);
            console.log(result.user);
            dispatch(addUser(result.user));
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    }
}


export function logout(){
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            await signOut(auth);
            dispatch(removeUser())
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding : `auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);` in my firebaseConfig file. but it's throwing an error saying: *[2023-02-21T20:54:26.489Z]  @firebase/auth: Auth (9.17.1): INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition*

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL is undefined in your code. did you mean to import it first? Follow the Web version 9 example, it shows you how to do what you're trying to do: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#modifying_the_auth_state_persistence

Comment: You import `onAuthStateChanged`, but don't use it anywhere. That function is actually the key to picking up the restored user sign-in, as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).